Does anybody know how to change the Timeline view for workflows in Dynamics?
I am working with Dynamics in the customer service hub. I keep running in to the problem that whenever a year-quarter is over, the workflows of the previous quarter disappear. In order to get them back I need to set a custom time-frame. Is there a way to set it up in such a way that all active workflows are visible in the customer service hub?
So far, I wasn't able to find anything online about this
